# localStorage on .hide .show elements

Tags: jquery

I have a web app that when a button clicks submit it loads ldap groups through JavaScript. From there, when a user clicks the group it loads the users. I have this laid out on a single HTML page with other divs acting as separate pages, such as password reset and account locking. To hide/show the divs from the nav:

```
$(document).on('click', '#navMenu li a', 
function(nav) {
    $('.navlinks').hide();
    $(this.getAttribute('data-tab')).show()
})
```

My issue right now is that once a user is added to a group via a modal form, on submit the form refreshes the page and send the user back to the first tab and shows the first div, instead of keeping the active div open.

I've written this `localStorage` snipped to try to use that route, but it's still refreshing back. Any ideas or hints?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var last_id = localStorage.getItem('tab_id');
    if(last_id) {
        $('ul.navbar-menu li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.navLinks').removeClass('active');
        $('.navbar-menu li a').eq(Number(last_id.match(/\d+/)[0])-1).addClass('active');
        $('#' + last_id).addClass('active');
    }
    $('ul.navbar-menu li a').click(function() {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.navbar-menu li a').removeClass('active');
        $('.navLinks').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#' + tab_id).addClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem('tab_id', tab_id);
    });
})
```

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue and what are you expecting to happen? Don't see an issue here.

Comment: Well, one code smell is your first version is using a delegate event listener, while the second version is not.

Comment: Updated issue and code snippet.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue